# XSD - compounding simpleType validation

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have an XSD type that validates an IP address (simplified):

```
<xs:simpleType name="ip-address">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I have an XSD type that validates an IP port

```
<xs:simpleType name="ip-port">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
     <xs:minInclusive value="1025"/>
     <xs:maxInclusive value="65535"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And I have an XSD type that validates a channel within the IP data

```
<xs:simpleType name="ip-channel">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
     <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
     <xs:maxInclusive value="1024"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I now wish to add another type that is basically a compound of the above, but with `':'` separators between each field.
The result being that the XML can have an attribute that reads `239.0.0.1:15001:1`.
This is a common notation in our company documentation and XML configuration. We've only recently branched into XML validation as part of unit testing.

Mooted solution:

```
<xs:simpleType name="pmc-source">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <!--<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}\:[0-9]{1,5}"/-->
      <xs:pattern value="[ip-address]\:[ip-port]\:[ip-channel]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The commented out pattern works roughly, but isn't as strict as its sub-parts because it performs no range checking. Plus, it is duplication of validation effort, because the address, port and channel validations must exist for other unrelated validation.

Is it possible to express one XSD simpleType in terms of other simpleTypes in XSD?
If so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one concatenate two given XSD data types into a new XSD data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020639/can-one-concatenate-two-given-xsd-data-types-into-a-new-xsd-data-type)

Comment: I think that this comes down (modulo the `:`) to the question of creating a simple type that concatenates the lexical spaces of two simple types, which is a very good question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020639/can-one-concatenate-two-given-xsd-data-types-into-a-new-xsd-data-type/44130240#44130240